# azure devops pipeline docker compose push task fails with: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/vsts/work/1/s/data'

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-compose

Compose Push Service throws the below error in my pipeline:

```
##[error]Unhandled: Failed find: 
EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/vsts/work/1/s/data'
```

[image]

Pipeline YAML- I am using Docker Compose commands, the Build is working fine, its the push to ACR fails

```
  # Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'GUID'
  imageRepository: 'strapiregimg'
  containerRegistry: 'strapireg.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

    enter code here


- task: DockerCompose@0
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
    azureSubscription: ''
    azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"strapireg.azurecr.io", "id" : ""}'
    dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
    action: 'Build services'
    includeSourceTags: true
    includeLatestTag: true

- task: DockerCompose@0
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
    azureSubscription: ''
    azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"strapireg.azurecr.io", "id" : "'
    dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
    action: 'Run services'

- task: DockerCompose@0
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
    azureSubscription: ''
    azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"strapireg.azurecr.io", "id" : ""}'
    dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
    action: 'Push services'
```

> Error is on Azure Pipeline only, locally it works well

Comment: please add your pipeline yaml.

Comment: Try removing the `docker run` prior to the `docker push` to make sure none of the files are locked or in use.

Comment: it worked, The files were locked by docker Run

Answer (score 1):

Posting the Answer based on [PGautami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2373139/pgautami) comment and supporting the statement given by [jessehouwing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736079/jessehouwing) to help the other community members with related discussions.

When you are using Docker compose commands to Push services through ACR if you run `docker run` command prior to `docker push` it will help you in preventing from file locks so that the Push command works.